# Parsing binary strings in one pass

Tags: parsing, rust

### The question

I want to parse string like below

1. Start with `0b`
2. You can add any `_` anywhere in the middle
3. From right to left, every 8digits is a group, and if it is insufficient, add 0 to fill up 8digits
4. Convert each group to `u8` according to binary analysis
5. Collect as bytes.

For example, start with `0b11_1001_0011_1001_00111001`

Fill leading zero and remove `_`: `00111001, 00111001, 00111001`

Convert to bytes: `[57, 57, 57]`.

---

### My Attempt

I wrote the following algorithm, but it generates too many intermediate strings

```rust
let binary = "0b11_1001_0011_1001_00111001";

fn parse_binary(binary : &str) {
    let digits: String = binary.chars().skip(2).filter(|c| *c != '_').collect();
    let length = 8 - digits.len() % 8;
    let filled = "0".repeat(length) + &digits;
    let mut bytes = Vec::with_capacity(filled.len() / 8);
    for chunk in filled.chars().collect::<Vec<_>>().chunks(8) {
        let chunk = chunk.iter().collect::<String>();
        let chunk = u8::from_str_radix(&chunk, 2).unwrap();
        bytes.push(chunk);
    }
    // [57, 57, 57]
    println!("{:?}", bytes);
}
```

Is it possible to parse to `Vec<u8>` without any string create and concatenation?

Comment: I would recommend you to take a look at the `nom` crate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to just read the string right to left, take each octet you encounter and convert it to a byte, and push onto a vec. At the end you reverse the vec to get it to be left-to-right

```rust
fn parse_binary(binary: &str) -> Result<Vec<u8>, String> {
    let mut chars = binary.chars();
    if chars.next() != Some('0') {
        return Err("first char wasn't 0".into());
    }
    if chars.next() != Some('b') {
        return Err("second char wasn't b".into());
    }

    let mut bytes = Vec::new();
    let mut curr_byte = 0_u8;
    let mut curr_byte_cursor = 0_u8;

    for c in chars.rev() {
        if curr_byte_cursor == 8 {
            bytes.push(curr_byte);
            curr_byte = 0;
            curr_byte_cursor = 0;
        }
        match c {
            '_' => {}
            '0' => curr_byte_cursor += 1,
            '1' => {
                curr_byte |= 1 << curr_byte_cursor;
                curr_byte_cursor += 1
            }
            _ => return Err(format!("invalid char {c:?}")),
        }
    }

    if curr_byte_cursor > 0 {
        bytes.push(curr_byte);
    }

    Ok(bytes)
}

fn main() {
    let binary = "0b1_1000_0000_00001111";
    println!("{:?}", parse_binary(binary));
    // Ok([1, 128, 15])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple [Iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) that will yield consecutive bytes. As an exercise you can add better error handling, as now this code will panic when it encounters unexpected character.

```rust
pub struct Parser<'s> {
    /// Iterator yielding bytes of data, has a lifetime of passed string
    data: std::iter::Rev<std::slice::Iter<'s, u8>>,
    /// Which bit of are byte will be next to fill
    bit: u8,
}

impl<'s> Parser<'s> {
    pub fn new(data: &'s str) -> Parser<'s> {
        assert!(data.starts_with("0b"));
        Self {
            // Skip first two bytes and then iterate in reverse
            data: data[2..].as_bytes().iter().rev(),
            bit: 0,
        }
    }
}

impl<'s> Iterator for Parser<'s> {
    type Item = u8;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        // Byte we will be oprating on
        let mut byte: u8 = 0;

        // Try to read 8 bits
        while self.bit < 8 {
            if let Some(x) = self.data.next() {
                match x {
                    b'0' => {
                        // Set self.bit-th bit to 0
                        byte &= !(1u8 << self.bit);
                    }
                    b'1' => {
                        // Set self.bit-th bit to 1
                        byte |= 1u8 << self.bit;
                    }
                    // Skip the rest of the loop when character is `_`
                    b'_' => continue,
                    c => panic!("Invalid character `{c}`"),
                }
            } else {
                if self.bit == 0 {
                    // There are no more characters in self.data && we finished
                    // reading full byte previously so we can finish iteration
                    return None;
                }
                // There are no more characters in self.data. Since byte has
                // initial value 0 remaining bits have already proper value
                // so we can skip the rest of the loop
                break;
            }
            // Prepare for the next iteration
            self.bit += 1;
        }
        // Reset self.bit for the following call of this function
        self.bit = 0;

        Some(byte)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need to *actually* pad the string. If you work from right to left, any leftover bits will naturally form the remaining byte.
- You don't need to *actually* remove the `0b` prefix or any `_` characters. You can just skip them during decoding.
- Use bit manipulation to compose each individual byte while scanning over the string.

Doing it all in a single pass does mean that you might over-estimate the capacity you pass into `Vec::with_capacity`, because you don't know up front how many `_`s you will encounter. This can be fixed, at the expense of needing another pass over the string, by first counting all the actual `0` and `1` characters.